# Can't call contact using Gmail's voice calling

Tags: gmail, chat, google-voice

I can call phone numbers and hangout with people, but I can't call a contact using the "Voice calling" feature. My contact says he doesn't get any notification when I try calling him. He can call me just fine, but I can't call him.

I'm using Mac OS X Mountain Lion and Google Chrome 26.

Comment: You need to have some cash on your account (at least here in Holland). So, basically your question concerns Google-Voice? Perhaps you can edit your question and loss some of the tags?

Comment: When in gmail, I click on a contact in my list of contacts in chat. A chat window opens up and I can text chat with them. But when I click the button that says "Voice calling" it says that I'm calling them on my end, but on my contact's end, he doesn't get a notification. If he calls _me_ then I get a notification and we can voice chat. But, it doesn't work if I call him.

Comment: Are you both in the U.S.?

Comment: Yes. I'm in CA and he's in HI.

Comment: Are you both using the same version of chat? There might be incompatibility between Hangouts and the old gChat

Comment: As said check whether he has the compatible devices for voice call with good connection hopefully it may help and also here check this source http://www.howtogeek.com/170940/8-reasons-you-should-be-using-google-voice-if-youre-american/ which may assist you with some idea.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the computer-to-computer voice calling option, correct? Then, I could think of only two options:

1. Make sure that he has not logged into his Gmail from mobile devices or any other devices that are not capable of supporting voice calling option.
2. Make sure that both of you are logged in. Sometimes, people try to call when they are on invisible status.